# ruby string concatenation (I think?)

Tags: ruby, string, string-concatenation

I'm just starting with "The Well-Grounded Rubyist", and they gave the following example:

```
print "Hello. Please enter a Celsius value: "
print "The Fahrenheit equivalent is ", gets.to_i * 9 / 5 + 32, ".\n"
```

In particular, I'm looking at line 2, where they seem to be using commas for string concatenation. I assume the `+` symbol isn't being used because of the `+ 32` portion of the code. However, can someone explain to me what the commas actually are doing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The commas are argument separators. The `print` method can take any number of arguments and will print them in sequence. Any string concatenation (if any occurs here) would take place inside the `print` method itself.

Answer (score 2):

The commas are delimiting the arguments to the print function.

Answer (score 1):

Argument separators, i.e. print is called with three arguments.